# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 on HikariDataSource

Tags: java, maven

I have Windows 7 and I am using maven to compile my codes on command line.  About 2 days ago, I had Java 6 SDK installed and that's what I was using to compile my codes.  Everything was working fine; the compiled war file would start on its own after tcserver is launched.  Yesterday, due to some other issue, I had to install Java 8 SDK.  This is when my problem started.

It turned out that the installation of Java 8 introduced some other problem.  So, I uninstalled Java 8 and rebooted.  After that, I could still compile my codes.  However, when I go to my tcserver manager and click Start on the process, I would get an error in the log file saying something about "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0".  After some researches, it appears to be a problem with Java 8.  But I did uninstall Java 8.  To make sure that I have Java 6 SDK installed, I uninstalled the Java 6 SDK, re-installed it, and then re-compile my codes.  That did not help and the log still shows the same error.

My mvn -v returns the followings,

```
Maven home: C:\installs\maven3\apache-maven-3.1.1
Java version: 1.6.0_45, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\installs\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

My echo %JAVA_HOME% returns the followings,
  C:\installs\Java\jdk1.6.0_45

My java -version returns the followings,

```
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)
```

From what I can see, the version of Java that is being used in compiling my codes appears to be 6.  Why am I still getting that Hikari error?  Where else do I need to fix to correct the problem?

Comment: Do you have a %JDK_HOME% set?

Comment: It is not set at all

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following steps:

1. First delete your local maven repository (usually in /.m2/repository).
   This would delete all installed jar-files (which may have been created with your JDK8)
2. call `mvn clean` (to clean all your files in the target directory
3. Check your %JDK_HOME% (may be it points to your JDK-8
4. Rebuild your project by `mvn package`

**But:**

```
1.6.0_45, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
```

This is really bad out-dated. You should update at least to Java7. There are unclosed security-issues in this version.

Comment: _45 was the version that I was using prior to installing Java 8 and it was working fine.  That's why I switched back to _45.

Comment: The command that I use to do the maven compile is mvn clean compile install

Comment: Have you cleaned your local repository? Do you use snapshot versions of libraries (which may be updated).

Comment: FYI, according to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html, _45 appears to be the most recent version of Java 6 I can download.  Unfortunately, for the branch that I am working on, hikari is configured to use Java 6.  It may not work by installing Java 7.

Comment: I never worked with hikar, but http://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/ reads as if the same library would be compatible with java7 (but not java8)

Comment: Yes, I did cleared my .m2 repository and then did a mvn package.  After all that, I removed the folder from webapps folder and put the new war file in.  The problem remains.

Comment: One more thing, not sure if this would shed any light on the problem.  I deployed an old war file that I generated few days ago before installing Java 8.  Everything works as usual.  The hikari problem only occurs when I use the newly generated war file.

Comment: With this said, does it mean that somehow my maven is still compiling the codes using Java 8?  But when I have checked the java version, maven version, JAVA_HOME, and JDK_HOME, everything is pointing to jdk 6 folder.  What else is missing?